# Add CSS class from model

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

I need to set CSS class according to a variable so I have:

```
<table class="info" data-ng-class="{ 'plan, {{vm.name}}': vm.name != null }">
```

When vm.plan is not null I add the classes plan and the value from vm.name.

However, this does not apply the styles of vm.plan. The following does:

```
<table class="info plan" data-ng-class="vm.name">
```

The problem is that I want only to add the class "plan" when I add "vm.name".

What I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Array notation can be more convenient here:

```
<table class="info" data-ng-class="[ vm.name != null ? 'plan ' + vm.name : '' ]">
```

or you can still use interpolation tags

```
<table class="info" data-ng-class="{{ vm.name != null ? 'plan ' + vm.name : '' }}">
```

if you like it more.